# Помогите переделать jQuery скрипт на vue js + js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Мне надо сделать чтобы textarea автоматически увеличивал высоту в зависимости от кол-ва символов. 
У меня есть такой скрипт на jquery

```
 $('textarea[data-auto-resize-height]').each(function () {
this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
})

$(document).on('input', 'textarea[data-auto-resize-height]', function () {
this.style.height = 'auto';
this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});
```

Мне надо переделать это на vue js с помощью `ref` 
Мне подсказали что надо в `mounted()` задать `this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');` а в `methods:`

```
this.style.height = 'auto';
this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
```

Но я никак не могу это до кучи собрать. Помогите плз. Ещей и на ecmascript 6 надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
<div id="app">
  <textarea @input="handler">
  </textarea>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    handler(e) {
        e.target.style.height = "5px";
        e.target.style.height = e.target.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } 
  }
})

textarea {
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, единственное что у меня ESlint пишет такую штуку Unexpected string concatenation. (prefer-template) как ее пофиксить?

Comment: Покурите гугл, смысл в том, что eslint хочет чтобы вы шаблонные  строки использовали, видимо вот так надо написать: \`${e.target.scrollHeight}px\`